# How can I use generic classes with a generic function in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

I had trouble figuring out how to phrase my question, but I have code like the following:

1. There's a generic class (`BaseOuter`) with a method (`to_inner`) whose return type is generic.
2. There are concrete subclasses of that generic class (e.g. `Outer`). When I call `Outer().to_inner()`, the inferred return type is `Inner` as I expect.
3. I create a generic function that takes an optional `BaseOuter` and calls `to_inner()` on it. But when I pass an `Outer` to this function, the inferred return type is `BaseInner`, and not `Inner` as I expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make type checkers realize that `to_inner(Outer())` returns an `Inner`?

```py
import typing

class BaseInner:
    pass

T_co = typing.TypeVar('T_co', bound=BaseInner, covariant=True)
T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound=BaseInner)


class BaseOuter(typing.Generic[T_co]):
    def to_inner(self) -> T_co:
        return self.InnerType()


@typing.overload
def to_inner(outer: BaseOuter[T]) -> T: ...
@typing.overload
def to_inner(outer: None) -> None: ...
def to_inner(outer: typing.Optional[BaseOuter[T]]) -> typing.Optional[T]:
    return outer.to_inner() if outer else None


class Inner(BaseInner):
    pass


class Outer(BaseOuter[Inner]):
    InnerType = Inner


this_is_an_Inner = Outer().to_inner()
unfortunately_a_BaseInner = to_inner(Outer())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `InnerType` annotation to `BaseOuter` generic class, because this name is used in `to_inner` method. Otherwise, `mypy` (0.910) will not be able to understand your intentions:

```
class BaseOuter(typing.Generic[T_co]):
    InnerType: typing.Type[T_co]   # <---
    
    def to_inner(self) -> T_co:
        return self.InnerType()
```